# python face_recognition module does not recognize any faces

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I'm trying to replicate this pattern-matching-like code in my machine but it wont recognize any faces on my webcam. I ran the exact code from the 2 sources but the result was the same, it loads the reference images and open the camera, but it does not detect anything. no errors.

https://pysource.com/2021/08/16/face-recognition-in-real-time-with-opencv-and-python/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tl2eEBFEHqM

here is the code:

```py
import face_recognition
import os, sys, cv2, math, dlib
import numpy as np

def face_confidence(face_distance, face_match_threshold=0.6):
    range = (1.0 - face_match_threshold)
    linear_value = (1.0 - face_distance) / (range * 2.0)
    if face_distance > face_match_threshold:
        return str(round(linear_value * 100, 2)) + '%'
    else:
        value = (linear_value + ((1.0 - linear_value) * math.pow((linear_value - 0.5)*2, 0.2))) * 100
        return str(round(value, 2)) + '%'
    
class FaceRecognition:
    face_locations = []
    face_encodings = []
    face_names = []
    known_face_encodings = []
    known_face_names = []
    process_current_frame = True
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.encode_faces()
    
    
    def encode_faces(self):
        for image in os.listdir('faces'):
            face_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(f'faces/{image}')
            face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face_image)
            self.known_face_encodings.append(face_encoding)
            self.known_face_names.append(image)
        print(self.known_face_names)
        
    def run_recognition(self):
        video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        
        if not video_capture.isOpened():
            sys.exit('camera não encontrada')
            
        while True:
            ret, frame = video_capture.read()
            
            if self.process_current_frame:
                small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
                rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:,:, ::-1]
                
                #find all the faces in current frame
                self.face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
                # self.face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, self.face_locations)
                self.face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(
                    rgb_small_frame,
                    [dlib.rectangle(*face_location) for face_location in self.face_locations]  # Convert face_locations to dlib rectangles
                )
                
                self.face_names = []
                for face_encoding in self.face_encodings:
                    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(self.known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                    name = 'Não Autorizado'
                    confidence = 'Unknown'
                    
                    face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(self.known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                    best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
                    
                    if matches[best_match_index]:
                        print('aaa')
                        name = self.known_face_names[best_match_index]
                        confidence = face_confidence(face_distances[best_match_index])
                        # print(confidence)
                        
                    self.face_names.append(f'{name} ({confidence})')
                    
            self.process_current_frame = not self.process_current_frame
                
            #Display Annotations
            for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(self.face_locations, self.face_names):
                top *= 4
                right *= 4
                bottom *= 4
                left *= 4
                
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0,0,255), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0,0,255), -1)
                cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)
                
                
            cv2.imshow("Face Recognition", frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break
                
        video_capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fr = FaceRecognition()
    fr.run_recognition()
```

Already tryed to create new conda envs and reinstall all involved packages.

this is my conda env btw:

```bash
(cv) [hnz@aspire-5 ~/Downloads/source code]$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/hnz/anaconda3/envs/cv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_openmp_mutex             5.1                       1_gnu  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
ca-certificates           2023.12.12           h06a4308_0  
click                     8.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
contourpy                 1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
dlib                      19.24.2                  pypi_0    pypi
expat                     2.5.0                h6a678d5_0  
face-recognition          1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
face-recognition-models   0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.47.2                   pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
libffi                    3.4.4                h6a678d5_0  
libgcc-ng                 11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libgomp                   11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libuuid                   1.41.5               h5eee18b_0  
matplotlib                3.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0  
numpy                     1.26.3                   pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.9.0.80                 pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   3.0.12               h7f8727e_0  
packaging                 23.2                     pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    10.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       23.3.1          py312h06a4308_0  
pyparsing                 3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5                     5.15.10                  pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-qt5                 5.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-sip                 12.13.0                  pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.12.0               h996f2a0_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0  
setuptools                68.2.2          py312h06a4308_0  
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.41.2               h5eee18b_0  
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0  
tzdata                    2023d                h04d1e81_0  
wheel                     0.41.2          py312h06a4308_0  
xz                        5.4.5                h5eee18b_0  
zlib                      1.2.13               h5eee18b_0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to indent two lines under `if` block and use `break` there:

```
if matches[best_match_index]:
     print('aaa')
     name = self.known_face_names[best_match_index]
     confidence = face_confidence(face_distances[best_match_index])
     # print(confidence)
     self.face_names.append(f'{name} ({confidence})')
     self.process_current_frame = not self.process_current_frame
     break
```

... but i's not easy to understand what you need your app to do.